# How to put a Widget in a Container

Tags: flutter, dart

#### Assumptions and what I want to achieve

I've added a background to the original TODO list code, and now I'm getting an error because there are two children.

#### Problems and error messages.

```
The argument for the named parameter 'child' was already specified.
```

The argument for the named parameter 'child' was already specified. ``` The message is probably due to two children.

#### ```` The argument for the named parameter 'child' was already specified.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(


        // Display the AppBar and set the title
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('List of Lists'),

      ),
      body: Container(
      height: _height,
      width: _width,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
      colors: [
      const Color(0xffe4a972).withOpacity(0.6),
      const Color(0xff9941d8).withOpacity(0.6), const Color(0xff9941d8).withOpacity(0.6),
      ],
      begin: Alignment.topRight,
      end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
      ),
      ),

　　　　　//↓ Error here
        child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: todoList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Card(

              child: ListTile(
              title: Text(todoList[index]),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),

 //↓ Error here
 child: FloatingActionButton(
           onPressed: () async {
             // "push" to transition to new screen
             // receive the value passed from the add list screen
             final newListText = await Navigator.of(context).push(
               MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                 // specify the list add screen as the destination screen
                 return TodoAddPage();
               }),
             );
             if (newListText ! = null) {
               // note that newListText will be null if we cancel it
               setState(() {
                 // add list
                 todoList.add(newListText);
               });
             }
           },
           child: Icon(Icons.add),
         ),
      ),
      // Create a ListView based on the data
    );
  }
}
```

#### Things I've tried

I changed child to childen.
I searched for a way to put a listview and floatingaction widget in a container, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Use column which will accept list of widgets, container only accepts one child as parameter

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the `FloatingActionButton` to the `Scaffold` widget instead of the `Container`:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(


        // Display the AppBar and set the title
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('List of Lists'),

      ),
      body: Container(
      height: _height,
      width: _width,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
      colors: [
      const Color(0xffe4a972).withOpacity(0.6),
      const Color(0xff9941d8).withOpacity(0.6), const Color(0xff9941d8).withOpacity(0.6),
      ],
      begin: Alignment.topRight,
      end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
      ),
      ),

        child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: todoList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Card(

              child: ListTile(
              title: Text(todoList[index]),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),

 
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
           onPressed: () async {
             // "push" to transition to new screen
             // receive the value passed from the add list screen
             final newListText = await Navigator.of(context).push(
               MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                 // specify the list add screen as the destination screen
                 return TodoAddPage();
               }),
             );
             if (newListText ! = null) {
               // note that newListText will be null if we cancel it
               setState(() {
                 // add list
                 todoList.add(newListText);
               });
             }
           },
           child: Icon(Icons.add),
         ),
      // Create a ListView based on the data
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this mean that "Container" can handle floatingActionButton as an argument?

Comment: @user17119951 No, the `Container` does not have a default argument for `FloatingActionButton`

Comment: I see. I understand.
Thank you very much.
That part was solved, but I got a new error.
Is it possible for you to answer my question again?

Comment: @user17119951 What's the new error?

Answer (score 0):

Not all widgets accept multiple child widgets. check [official documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/layout). For you question you can easily add a `FloatingActionButton` to the `scaffold` widget (not to `Container`) like below. I recommend to read about [flutter layouts](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout) to get a good understanding.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(


        // Display the AppBar and set the title
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('List of Lists'),

      ),
      body: Container(
      height: _height,
      width: _width,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
      colors: [
      const Color(0xffe4a972).withOpacity(0.6),
      const Color(0xff9941d8).withOpacity(0.6), const Color(0xff9941d8).withOpacity(0.6),
      ],
      begin: Alignment.topRight,
      end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
      ),
      ),//↓ Error here
        child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: todoList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Card(

              child: ListTile(
              title: Text(todoList[index]),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
        ),
 floatingActionButton:FloatingActionButton(
           onPressed: () async {
             // "push" to transition to new screen
             // receive the value passed from the add list screen
             final newListText = await Navigator.of(context).push(
               MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                 // specify the list add screen as the destination screen
                 return TodoAddPage();
               }),
             );
             if (newListText ! = null) {
               // note that newListText will be null if we cancel it
               setState(() {
                 // add list
                 todoList.add(newListText);
               });
             }
           },
           child: Icon(Icons.add),
         ),   // Create a ListView based on the data
    );
  }
```

Comment: I'll read the official documentation carefully.
Thank you very much for your instruction.